# Ruby on Rails - PDF not showing in production mode with Docker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker

I'm having a hard time figureing out the solution to my problem.
I have a ror application running in Docker. In development, the uploaded pdf get stored in `./storage` directory and they got rendered as expected on my application. In production, get uploaded in the same directory, but they don't get displayed.
I have checked the permissions on the directory and files and they seems to be ok.

My config:

**`storage.yml :`**

```
local:
  service: Disk
  root: <%= Rails.root.join("storage") %>
```

**`production.rb :`**

```
config.active_storage.service = :local
```

**`_attachment.html.erb :`**

```
<% if territory.file.previewable? %>
  <div class="container">
    <embed type="application/pdf" src="<%= rails_blob_path(@territory.file, disposition: :inline) %>" width="100%" height="500px">
  </div>
<% end %>
```

This partial gets rendered in my view like this:

```
<p>
  <%= render "territories/attachment", territory: territory %>
</p>
```

Am I missing something?
Thanks for any help and stay save out there!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was found!

Some packages wehere missing in the `Dockerfile`.

```
RUN apk add --update --no-cache  --virtual run-dependencies \
...
imagemagick \
less \
poppler-utils \
&& rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*
```